# Code behaves weird when platform target is set to Any CPU like WPF projects is ?

Tags: c#, wpf, console-application, aforge

This code should give me a collection of FilterInfo objects, representing the connected devices in the chosen category, which in this case is webcams.

```
FilterInfoCollection collection = new FilterInfoCollection(FilterCategory.VideoInputDevice);
```

I tested this in a console application, and it worked great, but when i bring the code into WPF, it only returns one object.

I tried using it directly in xaml codebehind and in viewmodel bound to xaml controls, but same result.

This is so bloody frustrating
Thanks in advance =)

EDIT:

I found the cause, the WPF project "Platform Target" is set to "Any CPU", and the console app is set to x86.
When i set the console app "Platform target" to "any cpu" it does exactly the same.

But unfortunately, the WPF project wont run when set to x86

Comment: I just tried to change the Target Framework, from client profile to full 4.0, but it didn't change a single thing.. WTF WPF

Comment: I also tried to get the devices from another thread. That didn't work either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried creating a new WPF project in the same solution, and now it works.
Sometimes i hate code with a passion... =P

Thanks for your help though!
I will keep my eyes open if this thing happens again.

Answer (score 0):

Taking a guess here but it sounds like the FilterInfoCollection is returning a difference based on whether the drivers are x64 or x86.

If you force it to compile in x86 mode then it's able to retrieve all of the x86 drivers.

Any CPU mode is going to execute in either x64 or x86 depending on the OS installed.  If it's a 64bit OS, then it will run in x64 mode.  This means it's only going to return x64 based drivers, of which it sounds like there is just one installed on your system.

Regarding issues in running a WPF application with a platform target of x86, you should provide more detail such as what error(s) you are seeing.  There shouldn't be an issue here: [Setting platform target to x86 on my x64 laptop prevent some WPF types to load properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3912276/setting-platform-target-to-x86-on-my-x64-laptop-prevent-some-wpf-types-to-load-pr)

Comment: I'm not actually seeing any errors. But when it is set to x86, it wont run any of the projects, it just lists them as skipped in the build console. Then nothing happens.

Comment: @Moulde: Go to configuration manager and select the x86 solution platform.  Mark all of the projects to build.  See: http://sedodream.com/CategoryView,category,WPF.aspx

Comment: They are already set to build in the x86 config. Yet they still gets skipped

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to change Target Framework from 4.0 to 3.5? Cause I had a similar issue and when I changed target framework it was good.