# Start process as 64 bit

Tags: c#, 32bit-64bit

I will like to show the onscreen keyboard. As a result I went to the following link on stackoverflow:

[Calling the on-screen keyboard using a button in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8800212/calling-the-on-screen-keyboard-using-a-button-in-c-sharp)

That technique works great when I am running my wpf application targeting the x64 platform. In other words it works when I set:

[image]

but if I set it to 86x it does not work. I need to run my application as x86 though. How can I solve this problem? I just have an exception when running my code on a x64 bit computer...

### Edit

I have temporary solution. What I did to solve this problem was to create a new project in Visual Studio (Console app) and named FooApplication targeting the x64 bit version. That program looks like:

```
Class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
         System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("osk.exe");
    }
}
```

then I am able to start the calculator my executing FooApplication.exe from my original wpf application.

Comment: Does this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3912276/setting-platform-target-to-x86-on-my-x64-laptop-prevent-some-wpf-types-to-load-p help?

Comment: It would likely be worthwhile to investigate _why_ your application doesn't run on X86-64 instead of trying to get a 64-bit application to run under a 32-bit operating system. If 32-bit is a requirement (and is not supported by your current solution) then you'll likely need to find another answer. Plain and simple, 64-bit applications are unwelcome on a 32-bit OS.

Comment: thanks for comments... I am making my wpf app run on purpose on 86 because I am using some sqlite dll's that only work on 32bit architecture. If I did not where to use those sqlite dll's then I will not get this error...

Comment: Sounds like you know the actual cause of your problem then. Recompile the sqlite DLLs for 64-bit and you should be all set.