# Process.Start can not find file specified, but it is definitely there - why?

Tags: c#, process

I am trying to run the DJOIN command from C#. (It is present by default in the c:\windows\system32 directory on Win 10.)

When I run the following:

```
ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo();
psi.UseShellExecute = false;
psi.FileName = @"c:\windows\system32\djoin.exe";
psi.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
psi.Arguments = "/C toast";
using (Process proc = Process.Start(psi))
{
using (StreamReader reader = proc.StandardOutput)
{
   string result = reader.ReadToEnd();
   MessageBox.Show(result);
}
```

I get a "file not found" error:

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception' occurred in System.dll    
Additional information: The system cannot find the file specified
```

[image]

However, if I use another "out of the box" .exe, such as "tasklist.exe" it works fine. E.g.:

```
proc.StartInfo.FileName = "tasklist.exe";
```

Gives me the following output:

[image]

Comment: What happens if you set `UseShellExecute` to `true`?  Is djoin.exe in your system path?

Comment: Why not specify the full path of the file?

Comment: it smells like a problem with the `path` variable.  What happens if you do `proc.StartInfo.FileName = @"c:\windows\system32\djoin.exe";`

Comment: @YacoubMassad - have tried that. Same error.

Comment: You have to specify the full path.

Comment: @SamIam - tried this, same error. :-(

Comment: Can you post the full exeception ToString()?

Comment: why are you creating `proc` if are only using the StartInfo to create another process?

Comment: @usr - System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005): The system cannot find the file specified
   at System.Diagnostics.Process.StartWithCreateProcess(ProcessStartInfo startInfo)
   at System.Diagnostics.Process.Start()
   at System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(ProcessStartInfo startInfo)
   at AMBootstrapper.MainWindow.Button_Click(Object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) in c:\..\MainWindow.xaml.cs:line 108

Comment: What happens when you open `cmd.exe`, then type `cd c:\windows\system32`, then type `djoin.exe /?`?

Comment: @Quantic - this works fine, i get the help text as expected

Comment: @Quantic (it also works from any directory, proving that the path variable is working properly)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can also disable to folder redirection for 64bit OS

```
[System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("Kernel32.Dll", EntryPoint = "Wow64EnableWow64FsRedirection")]
public static extern bool EnableWow64FSRedirection(bool enable);


        EnableWow64FSRedirection(false);

        try
        {
            ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo();
            psi.UseShellExecute = false;
            psi.FileName = @"c:\windows\system32\djoin.exe";
            psi.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            psi.Arguments = " /C toast ";
            using (Process proc = Process.Start(psi))
            {
                using (System.IO.StreamReader reader = proc.StandardOutput)
                {
                    string result = reader.ReadToEnd();
                    MessageBox.Show(result);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
        EnableWow64FSRedirection(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the issue was that DJOIN.exe is 64-bit. My app was running in 32-bit, so I changed the platform to X64 and it worked.

See: [Start process as 64 bit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13656389/start-process-as-64-bit)

Comment: Any bitness can start a process of any bitness. Your app probably was 32 bit virtualized and the OS pretended the file did not exist.

Comment: it was caused by folder redirection for the 64bit os

Answer (score -1):

Try to run the **cmd** command where your application is a parameter.
The following works for me:

```
ProcessStartInfo processInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd", @"djoin.exe /C toast");

processInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
processInfo.UseShellExecute = false;

Process ProcessObj = new Process();
ProcessObj.StartInfo = processInfo;

ProcessObj.Start();
```